# Error: Expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '.' token - Understand fstream

Tags: c++, file, fstream

I have a simple problem. I'm just learning how to use `fstream` to print to and from a data file, and I am just having issues compiling. I am getting the same error on lines 11 and 20 of this code. Also, I am not very sure if I am printing from the file properly at the end of the code.

The error I am getting is:

> 'Error: Expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '.' token'

for line 11 and for line 20 it is the same error, but with the character `<<` instead of `.`. I am also receiving this error:

> "error: expected unqualified-id before ‘if’"

for some reason, although I am pretty sure my syntax is correct on those. Are these errors somehow related? Here is my *main.cpp* file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

ofstream outFile;
string filename = "test.txt";

outFile.open(filename.c_str() );

if (!outFile) {
  cerr << "File "
       << filename
       << " failed to open for output."
       << endl;
}

outFile << "Hello world!"
        << 2013
        << 3.14
        << "The end."
        << endl;

outFile.close();

ifstream inFile;

inFile.open("test.txt");

if (!inFile) {
  cerr << "File "
       << filename
       << " failed to open for input."
       << endl;
}

int i=0;

while (inFile >> i) {

  cout<< i
  << endl;
  i++;
  cout<< "Year is: "
      << i
      << endl;
  i++;
  cout<< "PI is about: "
      << i
      <<endl;
  i++;
  cout<< i
  <<endl;  
}
```

Comment: Start smaller, like a hello world program, and you'll see what you're missing.

Comment: This doesn't appear to be in any method at all .. ?

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell you are missing `main` or some sort of `function` otherwise this is not a proper program, like:

```
int main()
{
    ofstream outFile;
    string filename = "test.txt";

    /// rest of your code
 }
```

The code that writes out the file looks like it works fine, the next problem is when you are reading your file back in here:

```
while (inFile >> i)
```

You have mixed data, it is not all `int` first of all and something like this would probably be better to start out with:

```
std::string str ;

while (std::getline(inFile, str))
{
        std::cout << str << std::endl ;
}
```